# ChartJS date reformatting for use?

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design, chart.js

I am having some trouble with my chartjs code. I have a date feed that send data to the charts seen below. While score, and day_7_average worked fine when converting to a list. I am having trouble the dates. the data format I receive is in the "const test" variable and I need it in the "const dates" variable. Based on the nature of the project I can not type them out every time. What is the best way of fixing this problem? thanks.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sentiment</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.6/Chart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <style>
  .bar { fill: steelblue; }
  body { background-color: #1c142c; }
  </style>

  <body>
    <div>
      <h1 style="font: 200; color: white;">What are people saying on social media?</h1>
      <canvas id="canvas""></canvas>
    </div>
  </body>


    <script>


var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d'); 


const test = [&#x27;2020-12-24&#x27;, &#x27;2020-12-25&#x27;, &#x27;2020-12-26&#x27;, &#x27;2020-12-27&#x27;, &#x27;2020-12-28&#x27;, &#x27;2020-12-29&#x27;, &#x27;2020-12-30&#x27;, &#x27;2020-12-31&#x27;]

const dates = ['2020-12-24','2020-12-25','2020-12-26','2020-12-27','2020-12-28','2020-12-29','20201-12-30','2020-12-31']

const score = [-2, -40, 81, -31, 34, -35, -24, -30]
const day_7_average = [0, -6, 3, -2, 5, 5, 0, -7]

window.chartColors = {
    red: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    orange: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
    yellow: 'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
    green: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
    blue: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
    purple: 'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
    grey: 'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
};

const colours = score.map((value) => value < 0 ? 'rgb(255, 99, 132)' : 'rgb(75, 192, 192)');

var chartData = {
    labels: dates,
    datasets: [{
       type: 'line',
       label: '7 day average',
       backgroundColor: 'rgb(201, 203, 207)',
       borderColor: 'rgb(201, 203, 207)',
       borderWidth: 2,
       fill: false,
       data: day_7_average,
            }, 
             {
                type: 'bar',
                label: 'Sentiment Score',
                backgroundColor: colours,
                data: score
            }]

        };
        window.onload = function() {
            
            window.myMixedChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartData,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    tooltips: {
                        mode: 'index',
                        intersect: false,
                    }
                }
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

Well... it may be a sloppy workaround but try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sentiment</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.6/Chart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <style>
  .bar { fill: steelblue; }
  body { background-color: #1c142c; }
  </style>

  <body>
    <div>
      <h1 style="font: 200; color: white;">What are people saying on social media?</h1>
      <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
  </body>


    <script>


var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d'); 


const test = ['&#x27;2020-12-24&#x27;', 
              '&#x27;2020-12-25&#x27;', 
              '&#x27;2020-12-26&#x27;', 
              '&#x27;2020-12-27&#x27;', 
              '&#x27;2020-12-28&#x27;', 
              '&#x27;2020-12-29&#x27;', 
              '&#x27;2020-12-30&#x27;', 
              '&#x27;2020-12-31&#x27;'];
        
var i;
dates_tmp = [];
for (i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  dates_tmp.push(String(test[i].replaceAll("&#x27;", "")));
}}
                
const dates = dates_tmp;
        
        
        
const score = [-2, -40, 81, -31, 34, -35, -24, -30]
const day_7_average = [0, -6, 3, -2, 5, 5, 0, -7]

window.chartColors = {
    red: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    orange: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
    yellow: 'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
    green: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
    blue: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
    purple: 'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
    grey: 'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
};

const colours = score.map((value) => value < 0 ? 'rgb(255, 99, 132)' : 'rgb(75, 192, 192)');

var chartData = {
    labels: dates,
    datasets: [{
       type: 'line',
       label: '7 day average',
       backgroundColor: 'rgb(201, 203, 207)',
       borderColor: 'rgb(201, 203, 207)',
       borderWidth: 2,
       fill: false,
       data: day_7_average,
            }, 
             {
                type: 'bar',
                label: 'Sentiment Score',
                backgroundColor: colours,
                data: score
            }]

        };
        window.onload = function() {
            
            window.myMixedChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartData,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    tooltips: {
                        mode: 'index',
                        intersect: false,
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    </script>
</html>
```

( Oh and by the way: You've got an unexpected " in line 16 )

Comment: Can you please drop in the full code? I can't seem to get this to run. Thanks!!

Comment: You had a couple of other mistakes (tags not closed, additional " ). It works for me like this... hope it does for you :)

Comment: This is AWESOME. You saved me such a headache thanks so much Nisch23.

Comment: No Problem ! :) Just note that I changed the elements in your const test to strings (I expect you will recieve them as strings in you final version?). If not we'll have to check if it works in the end...but glad I could help for now.

Comment: I noticed that. Am having trouble auto converting to string on the backend to make the push in the proper format. str(function) doesn't seem to be working as I hoped.

Comment: How do you recieve the data for const test ?   (can you post the line?). The way it is at the moment you'll get a SyntaxError.
Just to clearify: The "&#x27" is just the ASCII-Code for the single quote.

Comment: So it pushes from django like this: str(dates.values) which is ['2020-12-24', '2020-12-25', '2020-12-26', '2020-12-27', '2020-12-28', '2020-12-29', '2020-12-30', '2020-12-31']. I see this in my browser consol like const dates = [&#x27;2020-12-24&#x27;, &#x27;2020-12-25&#x27;, &#x27;2020-12-26&#x27;, &#x27;2020-12-27&#x27;, &#x27;2020-12-28&#x27;, &#x27;2020-12-29&#x27;, &#x27;2020-12-30&#x27;, &#x27;2020-12-31&#x27;] with no quotes